# Powershell - an empty pipe element is not allowed

Tags: powershell, csv

I keep receiving the following error message - "An empty pipe element is not allowed" whenever I try to pipe out my results to a csv file. Any idea why this might be happening?

```
$apps = Import-CSV apps.csv
$computers = Import-CSV compobj.csv
foreach($computer in $computers) {    
    $computerLob = $computer.lob
    $lobApps = $apps | ? {$_.lob -eq $computerLob}
    foreach($app in $lobApps){
       $appLocation = $app.location
       $installed=Test-Path "\\$computerHostname\$appLocation"
       $computerHostname = $computer.hostname     
       $results = new-object psobject -property @{Computer=$computer.hostname;App=$app.appname;Installed=$installed} | select Computer,App,Installed 
       $results 
    } 
} | Export-csv "results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

I've tried doing this:

```
$results | Export-csv "results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

within the foreach loop but it only returns the last record.

Comment: To perform an `Export-csv` one object at a time remember to add the `-Append` switch. This should allow you to identify which data is causing the problem. PS. why are you using a `select` on a new `PSObject`: that's just wasting cycles.

Comment: @Richard Thanks for the reply. Can you show me how you would go about doing this? Also why am I wasting cycles - is there a better way of doing this. Cheers

Comment: Re. my PS: just use the result of `New-Object PSObject …`, there is no need to perform the `Select` (it just creates a new PSObject with the named properties... which is repeating what the `New-Object` just did).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I believe the problem you are having is around the use of foreach and the the pipeline, you are processing your items in the foreach statement but still expecting them to be on the pipeline.

This is a common error and is explained in more detail in the article [Essential PowerShell: Understanding foreach](http://poshoholic.com/2007/08/21/essential-powershell-understanding-foreach/) and [Essential PowerShell: Understanding foreach (Addendum)](http://poshoholic.com/2007/08/31/essential-powershell-understanding-foreach-addendum/).

You should be able to achieve what you want like this:

```
$apps = Import-CSV apps.csv
$computers = Import-CSV compobj.csv
$computers | foreach {
    $computer = $_
    $computerLob = $computer.lob
    $lobApps = $apps | ? {$_.lob -eq $computerLob}
    $lobApps | foreach {
       $app = $_
       $appLocation = $app.location
       $installed=Test-Path "\\$computerHostname\$appLocation"
       $computerHostname = $computer.hostname     
       new-object psobject -property @{Computer=$computer.hostname;App=$app.appname;Installed=$installed} 
    } 
} | Export-csv "results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 18):

A foreach loop doesn't ouput to the pipeline.  You can make it do that by making the loop a sub-expression:

```
$apps = Import-CSV apps.csv
$computers = Import-CSV compobj.csv
$(foreach($computer in $computers) {    
    $computerLob = $computer.lob
    $lobApps = $apps | ? {$_.lob -eq $computerLob}
    foreach($app in $lobApps){
       $appLocation = $app.location
       $installed=Test-Path "\\$computerHostname\$appLocation"
       $computerHostname = $computer.hostname     
       $results = new-object psobject -property @{Computer=$computer.hostname;App=$app.appname;Installed=$installed} | select Computer,App,Installed 
       $results 
    } 
}) | Export-csv "results.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 6):

Some of flow-control expressions do not stream their output. 
But they can be assigned to variables, but no output streaming.

You can put your expression output stream in a Subexpression `$()` and then pipe with another command.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pipe from ANY powershell statements.  I'm not sure why.

if .. else
   Switch
   Do .. while
   ForEach
   For
   While

EDIT:  Another way.  You can stream from a call operator and a scriptblock (or a function).  Put the foreach or any other statement inside it.  You won't have to wait until it finishes.

```
& { foreach ($i in 1..3) { $i } } | measure

Count             : 3
Average           : 
Sum               : 
Maximum           : 
Minimum           : 
StandardDeviation : 
Property          :
```