# How to pipe the result of a foreach loop into a csv file with PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint, powershell

I am having the following syntax problem, and I am still unsure if this is possible or not.

```
An empty pipe element is not allowed.
```

The script is

```
$web = get-spweb https://xx.com/sites/billing
$list = $web.Lists["Bill Cycles"]
foreach($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
{
   if ($wf.Name -like "*2013*")
   {  
      foreach($listitem in $list.Items)
      {
          foreach($Workflow in $listitem.Workflows)
          {
             if($wf.InternalStatus -ne "Completed")
             {
                if($Workflow.AssociationId -eq $wf.Id)
                {
                    New-Object psobject -Property @{
                            "InternalStatus" = $wf.InternalStatus
                            "WFName" = $wf.Name
                            "ListItemName" = $listitem.Name
                            "Url" = $listitem.Url
                            "Days" = ((Get-Date) - $Workflow.Created).Days
                    }
                }
             }
          }
      }
    }
} | Select-Object InternalStatus, WFName, ListItemName, Url, Days | Export-CSV $output -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make a foreach loop output to the pipeiline by using a sub-expression:

```
$web = get-spweb https://xx.com/sites/billing
$list = $web.Lists["Bill Cycles"]
$(foreach($wf in $list.WorkflowAssociations)
{
   if ($wf.Name -like "*2013*")
   {  
      foreach($listitem in $list.Items)
      {
          foreach($Workflow in $listitem.Workflows)
          {
             if($wf.InternalStatus -ne "Completed")
             {
                if($Workflow.AssociationId -eq $wf.Id)
                {
                    New-Object psobject -Property @{
                        "InternalStatus" = $wf.InternalStatus
                        "WFName" = $wf.Name
                        "ListItemName" = $listitem.Name
                        "Url" = $listitem.Url
                        "Days" = ((Get-Date) - $Workflow.Created).Days
                    }
                }
             }
          }
      }
    }
}) | Select-Object InternalStatus, WFName, ListItemName, Url, Days | Export-CSV $output -Delimiter ',' -NoTypeInformation
```

You can also use a scriptblock invocation (wrap the loop in `&{}` instead of `$()`  )

Answer (score 1):

A `foreach` loop doesn't output to the pipeline, so it's likely `Export-CSV` hasn't got any input.

Try [wrapping the iteration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19655955/503046) of WorkflowAssociations in parenthesis.